# How does broadcasting work on a server with multiple IPs?

Tags: networking, freebsd, subnet, isc-dhcp

Say you have two dhcp servers, A and B.

Server A has two IP addresses, 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2.
Server B has one IP address, 10.0.0.3.

Server A has two instances of isc-dhcp running, one specifying a local-address of 10.0.0.1 and the other specifying the local-address of 10.0.0.2.

Server B has one instance of isc-dhcp running, specifying a local-address of 10.0.0.3.

If you have another subnet separate from the dhcp servers, 192.168.0.0/24. This subnet's pool is hosted under the instance of isc-dhcp on Server A with IP 10.0.0.1. This subnet is behind a cisco device with the statement "ip helper-address 10.0.0.1". Routes are in place to reach that subnet just fine.

If a device is plugged into the switch/router with the ip helper statement and subnet of 192.168.0.0/24, how does both instances on Server A receive the discover while Server B does not? Both 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2 on Server A are on the same interface.

What I don't understand is why an interface would share discovers with both IPs on it, if that is indeed what happens. If it does share it, why doesn't isc-dhcp see what IP the packets are intended for rather than assuming because it hit the IP it's listening on then it must be for it.

My only guesses:

1. Either it's a networking thing I don't know about or understand.
2. The interface itself passes the packet to all IPs on it and isc-dhcp assumes regardless of what IP it listens on that all packets hitting that IP should be looked at and used.
3. There's nothing in the packet once it gets to the server identifying that it's for a specific IP only, both IPs get the data much like a hub would function, and therefore isc-dhcp HAS to assume if it hits the IP it listens on that it's to be used.

Rewrote the entire question to hopefully clarify the situation. Hopefully I didn't make it worse..

Comment: When a DHCP server receives a broadcast request, it **isn't sent to a specific IP**.  It is a broadcast that is received by an interface.  If you are trying to having two DHCP servers listen on a single interface, then you are doing something seriously broken.  Also, I am having a difficult time parsing your question about two IPs instead of a 3rd.  You need to explain that more.

Comment: @Zoredache I've edited the question a bit, which might make it a bit too elaborate, but may clarify some of your confusion if you can follow it all. We use a cisco switch with an IP Helper statement, which I was under the impression forces specific protocols (bootp being one of them) to a single IP rather than across the whole network.

Comment: This is why running multiple Layer 3's on a single Layer 2 is Bad Idea (TM). I can't make sense of the question either.

Comment: So is the DHCP server on the same subnet as the switch?  Generally the helper address is only used when packets are being forwarded across a router.

Comment: I rewrote the entire question, so hopefully it's easier to follow. Sorry for making it so complicated, but it's a fairly complicated question in my opinion. Both DHCP servers are one one subnet and the switch is on another.

Comment: This is certainly a strange one. Can you post the relevant section of your router configuration?

Comment: How are you confirming that both instances on Svr A received the DHCP request?  This sounds like isc-dhcp is binding to *all* addresses.  Use netstat to see if you have a binding like  0.0.0.0:67 or if 10.0.0.1:67 and 10.0.0.2:67 are present.  Is isc-dhcp running as a single process/instance or multiple?

Answer (score 1):

A typical DHCP transaction has 4 steps ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Technical_details))

1. Discover
2. Offer
3. Request
4. Ack

The router with the "ip helper-address 10.0.0.1" statement converts the **discover** broadcast of the dhcp-client to an unicast towards 10.0.0.1.

10.0.0.1 will sent an **offer** as a unicast back to the ip-helper-router who will convert it in a broadcast.

A client can receive dhcp-offers from multiple dhcp-servers, but will send only one **request** (generally to the server with the first offering). If all goes well the server concludes with a **ack**.